# Unbalanced longitudinal model with lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, longitudinal-data-analysis

I would like to asses the treatment effect on blood hormone concentration. Data are collected in 10 centers, at 4 time points (0,6,12,and 18 months). However four centers used both treatments a and b, and six centers used only treatment b. My current model is (treatment as factor and time as numeric):

```
lmer(outcome ~ treatment * time + (time | subject))
```

I wonder how to assess center effect, as the majority of centers did not use treatment a.

Comment: Adjusting for center as a fixed effect will account for heterogeneity in the baseline factors with mild exacerbation of errors but correct inference. If there are undetected interactions with treatment, the interpretation of effect is a little dicey.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you would want to include a random effect for the `center` grouping factor would be to account for correlations in your `outcome` variable for subjects coming from the same center. You could test if this is required via a likelihood ratio test, e.g.,

```
fm1 <- lmer(outcome ~ treatment * time + (time | subject), data = your_data)
fm2 <- lmer(outcome ~ treatment * time + (time | subject) + (1 | center), data = your_data)
anova(fm1, fm2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As subjects are nested within center I was thinking to use: fm3 <- lmer(outcome ~ treatment * time + (time | center/subject), data = your_data)

Comment: It may not be necessary that you also need a random slope in the center level; you will need to test for that using a likelihood ratio test.